# Rigorous formulation of Shannon-Hartley theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, information-theory

The [Shannon-Hartley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) theorem gives an expression for the capacity of a bandwidth and power limited channel. How would one formulate this theorem mathematically (rigorously)? I understand the formula given, but not how to formulate the assumptions made mathematically.

Comment: See eg Cover & Thomas, chapter 9

Comment: Cover& Thomas have a very sketchy treatment of the band-limited channel.